# Set one of the deep values of an array to be the key

Tags: php, arrays, mapping

**Background**

Say you have an array that looks like this, and we know that the `id` value is unique:

```
[
    0 => [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'First item'
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Second item',
    ],

    ...
]
```

**Question**

Is there a way to map this array to one that places the `id` value as the key, while keeping the rest of the value intact?

**Desired result**

Noticing now that the keys of the array matches the `id` value, the ideal result would be:

```
[
    5 => [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'First item'
    ],
    10 => [
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Second item'
    ]

    ...
]
```

**Minor detail**

For my purposes, whether or not the `id` key/value pair still exists in the array is unimportant, but I expect that if a solution exists to one case, the other solution would not differ by much.

Comment: Edited the `id`s to make it more obvious.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Aha, sorry. No, I haven't given up. I just haven't gotten back around to it because of work. I'll be back with that checkmark soon. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a built-in array function for that:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'id');
```

If `id` doesn't exist in a sub-array then it will increment from the previous and may be overwritten if that key is an `id` later.

Answer (score 0):

Loop approach:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[$v['id']] = $v;
}
```